# Is there a way to set globally a cmake property?

Tags: cmake

Let's say I build multiple cmake-based projects. I want to build them with a global property always defined.

For example, let's say I want to build always with [sccache](https://github.com/mozilla/sccache). For that, for each project, I need to do:

```
cmake <dir> -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=sccache -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=sccache
```

I end up writing that a lot, so it'd be useful to avoid it. I know I can create a wrapper for my C compiler that calls into `sccache`, and:

```
export CC=/path/to/sccache/gcc
```

(for example).

Similarly, I could write a wrapper or shell alias on top of `cmake` that just called `cmake -D...`.

But I would've expected to be able to do something like:

```
export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=sccache
export CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=sccache
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this. Is there one? I generally don't like to change `CC` and `CXX` globally because they may cause issues with other build systems or what not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if a dedicated toolchain script may be helpful for your needs.

Give a look at its documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html)

Then you would have to define `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<toolchain_script>` each time you want to use that preset of variables.